# Swift SIMD rounding errors in making 90 degree rotation matrix with sin, cos

Tags: swift, matrix, vector, rotation, simd

I'm following [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/working_with_matrices#2970111) about working with matrices with the accelerate framework.

There they using something similar to this to rotate a vector:

```swift
func makeRotationMatrix(angle: Float) -> simd_float3x3 {
    let rows = [
        simd_float3(cos(angle), -sin(angle), 0),
        simd_float3(sin(angle),  cos(angle), 0),
        simd_float3(0,           0,          1)
    ]

    return float3x3(rows: rows)
}

let vector = simd_float3(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1)
let angle = Measurement(value: 180, unit: UnitAngle.degrees)
let radians = Float(angle.converted(to: .radians).value)
let rotationMatrix = makeRotationMatrix(angle: radians)
let rotatedVector = rotationMatrix * vector

print("vector:", vector)                // SIMD3<Float>(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
print("angle:", angle)                  // 180.0 °
print("radians:", radians)              // 3.1415927
print("rotatedVector:", rotatedVector)  // SIMD3<Float>(-0.99999994, -1.0000001, 1.0)
```

I expected the `x` of the rotated vector to be `-1` instead of `-0.99999994`. I guess this is caused by the radians being a float? We could correct for this by rounding by hand:

```
let correctedVector = simd_float3(
    x: rotatedVector.x.rounded(),
    y: rotatedVector.y.rounded(),
    z: rotatedVector.z.rounded()
)
print("correctedVector:", correctedVector) // SIMD3<Float>(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to rotate this vector without rounding errors?

Comment: Don't expect trigonometry functions `sin` and `cos` to be precise. If you need to rotate precisely by 90/180/270 degrees, just pass canned matrix. Or even shuffle the elements instead of multiplication.